# how to configure jdbc connection pool in tomcat and use in jersey

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jdbc, jersey

Hi i am trying to get database connection from connection pool. This is the code i am using to get connection. I am using maven and jersey for creating rest services and tomcat 8.

```
    Context ctx;
    DataSource ds = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
         ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/project");
    } catch (NamingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i am getting exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/project] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

The resource code written in tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
 <Resource name="jdbc/project" global="jdbc/project" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="root" password="gaian"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/project" maxActive="150"
          maxWait="10000" initialSize="10"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          maxIdle="3"/>
```

the code in tomcat/conf/context.xml

```
 <ResourceLink name="jdbc/project"
    global="jdbc/project"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    />
```

how to resolve the above problem please help me with this

Thank you

Comment: You have defined the resource in the context.xml in your tomcat?

Comment: no, i defined resource in server.xml and resourcelink in context.xml of tomcat

Comment: Anything in any of the log files? There is usually an error first that causes the resource to not be created.

Comment: no i didn't find any thing like errors

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a reference in web.xml?

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/project</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```